# trying to use gradient to have center of my header color near white

Tags: css

Im trying to do a gradiente with css but Im not having sucess.

I have a purple logo at center of my header, and I like to see purple with white, but I dont want my whole header white.

So Im trying to have my header blue, and at center where I have my logo I want a gradient that allows me to have whiter center so I can put my logo there.

I want something like this:

Blue and at center where I want to put my logo I want to have something like white background.

[image]

Im trying to do this effect but Im not having the result that Im looking for.

You can see here what Im getting: http://jsfiddle.net/BA9Ry/2/

My html:

```
<header id="top">
    <span id="logo">
       <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/11ls8li.png"   />
    </span>
</header>
```

css:

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:none;

}

    #top
    {
        width:800;
        height:auto;
        margin:0 auto 0 auto;
        background:#7088A8;
         background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left center, right center, from(#7088A8), to(#fff));
    }

    #logo img {
        width:200px;
        height:100px;
        display:block;
        margin:0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/BA9Ry/3/ This is created with this tool http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/.

Comment: See what Miljan posted, you need to use a radial gradient instead of what you have (linear)

Comment: looks like the use of `-webkit-gradient` is too old, don't really need to support such old browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use this syntax:
    `background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#FFF, #7088A8);`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but like that my header looks very dark and I dont want that! (http://jsfiddle.net/BA9Ry/4/) I want just a small gradient to have my center near to white!

Answer (score 1):

this is the line you need

```
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(#ff, #7088a8);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Miljan Puzović's comment answer, you'll need to use `radial-gradient` instead of `gradient(linear, ...)`.

As you can see from the **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BA9Ry/3/)** he provided, there are several different prefixes given to each `radial-gradient`. If for whatever reason you don't need to support older browsers, you can drop all of them except for `-webkit-radial-gradient()` and `radial-gradient()`. For IE 9 and below support, you'll need to user Microsoft's proprietary `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient()`.

Calling `background:` before all the `radial-gradient`s will give old browsers a single colour background to use if they don't support radial backgrounds.

**CSS from the JSFiddle:**

```
#top {
    background: #c5e0f4; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #c5e0f4 0%, #60abf8 78%, #6b98c4 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,#c5e0f4), color-stop(78%,#60abf8), color-stop(100%,#6b98c4)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #c5e0f4 0%,#60abf8 78%,#6b98c4 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #c5e0f4 0%,#60abf8 78%,#6b98c4 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #c5e0f4 0%,#60abf8 78%,#6b98c4 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #c5e0f4 0%,#60abf8 78%,#6b98c4 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#c5e0f4', endColorstr='#6b98c4',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

**Browser Support:**

You can read more on the support of browsers [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients). As you can see `-webkit-radial-gradient` is still required for most iOS/Android browsers.

**Full Syntax:**

You can see more about the full syntax of `radial-background` on [Mozilla's Developer Network Website](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/radial-gradient).